# Stored procedure for login

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql-server-2008

I have a `user` table with these columns:

```
    user_id
    user_name
    password
    createdate
    full_name
    location
    dep_id
    user_type
```

and I have a login form which includes username and password.

In this I create a splogin

```
create procedure splogin
  @User_Name nvarchar(50),
  @Password nvarchar(50)
as
  Select * from [User] 
  Where User_Name = @User_Name
    and Password = @Password
```

Then I want to know that is `usertype` is mention in login form or user profile form?

And through login form any user can be login

i.e manager, director and exectuive which approved document
and simple user whcih only upload documents

Comment: Please please do not store clear text passwords in your database. http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/ Please consider using the new webpages simple membership provider. It's really rather good and quite well thought out... and it *should* play nice with your existing data.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is considered bad practice to store passwords in the database (anyone on your team with DB access can see all of them).  Rather, you should store a one-way hash or checksum in the database, and then during login, recreate the one way hash or check sum from the submitted password, and see if it matches what is in the DB.

But to your question, It sounds like you are trying to combine Authentication (verifying that you are who you say you are)  and Authorization (Are you allowed to do what you are trying to do)

These two functions should be kept separate from one another.  Combining them into one function is also bad practice and can lead to numerous difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to perform security using user objects.  IF this is the case. I would create a user object using what your 'Select' statement returns.

Basic class

```
class UserObj
UserName
Location
DepartmentID
UserType
```

Then store that in Session. Like so:

```
Session["CurrentUser"] = UserObj;
```

Then whenever you want to perform verification. Get the object out of session.

```
UserObj currentUser = (UserObj)Session["CurrentUser"];
```

And see if it has a valid usertype

```
if(currentUser.UserType == "Director")
{
  //run this code
  //hide objects
  grid_BusinessStuff.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: usertype is in login form or in user profile?

Comment: nad please can u explain your code...not understand your answer